# How to get multiple video feed on the same website using Javascript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a website where it will take multiple video feed from the same camera and display on the webpage. I am using Javascript and HTML. I am new to both and have established one video feed on the webpage. However I need multiple. Please help me. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<head>
  <meta charset="uft-8">
  <title>Web Stream</title>
  <style>
    video {
      margin:200px ;
      margin-left: 500px;
      width:650px;
      height:500px;
      border:10px #333 solid;
      background-color: #666
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<video autoplay='true' id='videoElement' allign="middle">
</video>

<script>
var video=document.querySelector("#videoElement");

navigator.getUserMedia=navigator.getUserMedia||navigator.webkitGetUserMedia||navigator.mozGetUserMedia||navigator.msGetUserMedia||navigator.oGetUserMedia;
if(navigator.getUserMedia){
navigator.getUserMedia({video:true},handleVideo,videoError);
}

function handleVideo(stream){
video.srcObject = stream;
video2.scrObject= stream;
}
function videoError(e){
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: First thing i would try is creating a second video element and define the variable `video2`.

Comment: I have tried a second variable called video2, however I end up getting only one feed. Maybe I am not doing it right.

Comment: I don't know if you can asign a stream to two video elements... but i would try it by adding `<video autoplay='true' id='videoElement2' allign="middle"></video>` and `var video2=document.querySelector("#videoElement2");` to your code.

Comment: here an example that shows the screen in two video elements: https://jsfiddle.net/h7xztLqc/

Comment: It's deprecated, but if you use `URL.createObjectURL()` for the MediaStream, you can assign it to several video elements.  They can even be in different windows!